# Behavior of $P(A > B \mid A, B < \kappa)$ as a function of $\kappa$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume two independent and continuous variables $A$ and $B$, with densities $f_A$ and $f_B$. Let $F_A$ and $F_B$ denote the their respective cumulative distribution functions, with $F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x) \;\; dx$. Finally, assume that $\mathbb{E}(A) \geq \mathbb{E}(B)$.

Now, consider the probability that a sample from $A$ is larger than a sample from $B$, conditional on both samples being below a value $\kappa$; i.e., $P(A > B \mid A, B < \kappa)$. This probability is given by $$R(\kappa) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\kappa \frac{f_A(x)F_B(x)}{F_A(\kappa)F_B(\kappa)} \;\; dx.$$

I am trying to show that $R(\kappa)$ is monotonically increasing function. When differentiating over $\kappa$, I end up with $$R(\kappa)^\prime = \frac{f_A(\kappa)}{F_A(\kappa)} - R(\kappa)\times\left(\frac{f_A(\kappa)}{F_A(\kappa)} + \frac{f_B(\kappa)}{F_B(\kappa)}\right).$$

So far so good, now I just need to show that $R(\kappa)^\prime$ is strictly non-negative. But this where I am stuck.

The reason why I am trying to show this is that I found this pattern with different families of distributions, like the Normal (same $\sigma^2$ for both $A$ and $B$) and the exponential. See the Figure attached below.

[image: example using a Normal and exponential distributions]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental theorem of calculus states the following,

Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function defined on $[a,b]$ and let $F$ be a function defined on $[a,b]$ by $$F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt.$$
Then $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and
$$F'(x) = f(x), x \in(a,b)$$

Therefore I think, with your 
$$R(k)=\int_{-\infty}^k {f_A(x)F_B(x) \over F_A(k)F_B(k)}dx$$
$$R'(k) = {f_A(k)F_B(k)\over F_A(k)F_B(k)}={f_A(k)\over F_A(k)} > 0 ,$$
since $f_A(x)\ge0$ for all $x$.

Could you explain how you arrived at your derivative of $R(k)$?

Comment: Pulled the denominator out of the integral, applied product and quotient rules. 

Your solution ignores the role of $B$, and this is an essential part of the function yielding $P(A>B \mid A,B < \kappa)$. Consider the following example: If $f_A = f_B$, then the integral is .50 for all $\kappa$, which means that the derivative is 0. Your solution is a reverse hazard, and not zero.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious that $R'(k)$ should consider the distribution of B into account. Thanks for pointing that out.